# Scanning dll files after buying library

Tags: security, unity-game-engine, dll

I want to buy a library for windows to capture video and audio to use it in my Unity application from unknown publish.

How to check if the library (.dll file) may contain a virus or malware or a hack tool.

Is there any tool or a trusted website that do this?

I know I must buy only from trusted places like unity store but this library is not found in unity store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you never can not be 100% sure, even when buying from unity asset store.
What is more if you would get source code, hack could be hidden very well in plain sight.

What you can do is scan file by your antivirus (if you have one) or alternatively run https://www.virustotal.com

Comment: You mean for virus and malware and trojans I can be sure 100% using antivirus software, but for hack and other things that can be written in the code it can't be checked unless I see the source code?

Comment: If this dll is .net you can use ILSpy to browser code and check if there are any potentials problems. 
If dll is not .net you could also read file using some disassembler but it would be very time consuming. Probably creating own solution would be faster than verifying 3d party dll